# Can I publish two apps with same name on play store?

Tags: android, ios

Can two app be published with the same name and be available only in the selected country, for example:

''APPNAME''- v.1 this app connect only to Slovenian server and should be only visible in Slovenia

''APPNAME'' - V.2 this app connects only to the Italian server and should be only visible in Italy.

Is it possible to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: I have done this before, but I don't know if it is still possible, you can always just ask google support, and get a direct answer

Comment: try using Build Flavors in your project

Answer (score 2):

Google play console allow you to specify in which countries your app can be visible/downloaded. You can customise app for different countries if it necessary, so there is no need in two apps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can publish an app with the same name.

But the Package name must be different.

Eg.

```
App Name1: APPNAME
package name1: appname.v1
```

and for other app

```
Eg. App Name2: APPNAME
package name2: appname.v2
```

Here Package name must be different.

**Also, you can publish an app country wise.**

For publishing app country wise,

1. Go to Playstore developer console
2. In-Store Presence, select pricing & distribution.
3. In the Country, section click on MANAGE COUNTRIES
4. Now you can select available and Unavailable countries